# PHP - how to switch between site styles and have one as default

Tags: php

i have this code here - i can switch between site styles using radio buttons, but when the site is loaded for a first time there is no style. I want to have a "light" theme when site loads and be able to switch between light and dark theme using those buttons. Can anyone give me a hand with this? Thanks.

```
<head>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and isset($_POST["style"])){
    if ($_POST["style"] == 1){
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">';
    } else {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-dark.css">';
    }
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<form action="site.php" method="post" class="form-1">
    Row: <input type="number" name="rows"><br>
    Column: <input type="number" name="columns"><br>
    Light Theme (default): <input type="radio" name="style" value="1"><br>
    Dark Theme: <input type="radio" name="style" value="2"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create table">
</form>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing and else path?

```
<head>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and isset($_POST["style"])){
    if ($_POST["style"] == 1){
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">';
    } else {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-dark.css">';
    }
}else {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">';
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<form action="site.php" method="post" class="form-1">
    Row: <input type="number" name="rows"><br>
    Column: <input type="number" name="columns"><br>
    Light Theme (default): <input type="radio" name="style" value="1"><br>
    Dark Theme: <input type="radio" name="style" value="2"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create table">
</form>
```

Comment: Use one `if` it will be easier, `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["style"]) && $_POST["style"] == 2){ echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-dark.css">'; } else { echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">';}`

Comment: @Faxder FYI and since you're new contributor, consider  accepting the answer if correctly satisfy your issue. ;)